# Credentials popup keeps popping up after El Capitan upgrade

Tags: macos, keychain

Display of problem here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lU_d1P-qX1s (10 seconds long)

I'm a developer and have all sorts of programs installed, including `SourceTree` and `GitHub`'s desktop app.  Unfortunately, in the last few days, since upgrading to `El Capitan` this continues to happen to me.

When I'm working, or just using the computer at all, a credentials question pops up front and centre, asking me if I want to allow `git-credential-sourcetree` access to `github.com` in my `keychain`, full message

```
git-credential-sourcetree wants to use your confidential information stored in "github.com" in your keychain.

Do you want to allow access to this item?

Always Allow | Deny | Allow
```

My first click, and preference is `Always allow`, but if I click that, or `Allow`, nothing seems to happen.  Only when I click `Deny` does the prompt seem to take on board what my choice is.  After I click `Deny`, the popup disappears, but always pops up once more, and only stays away if I click `Deny` again, as shown in the clip.

It's really distracting and irritating, especially given that I really do want `SourceTree` to be able to access that login information (`SourceTree` was the original program I inputted my login information for `Github`).

Comment: Same issue here - but no MagicPrefs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've received the answer to my problem from finchr's post at https://discussions.apple.com/message/29270520#29270520,

> In my case the problem was with MagicPrefs, a utility that lets you define additional mouse and trackpad gestures.  Disabling MagicPrefs allows Keychain to see Allow/Allow All mouse clicks.

Which was the very same for me.  I haven't permanently disabled, or uninstalled MagicPrefs, I just disable it when I need to click one of those boxes.  Hopefully they or Apple will come out with an update that fixes this.